# How do I switch to a specific track by index in Exoplayer?

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

I am creating a music player using Exoplayer. If the user clicks on a specific track from recyclerview I want to play all tracks but switch to clicked index.

I am using `ConcatenatingMediaSource` to play the playlist.

```kotlin
val concatenatedSource = ConcatenatingMediaSource()

for (v in videos) {
    when (v.type) {
        "join" -> {
            val mediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(cacheDataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(v.src))
            concatenatedSource.addMediaSource(mediaSource)
        }
        "separate" -> {
            val videoSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(cacheDataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(v.vSrc))
            val audioSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(cacheDataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(v.aSrc))
            val mergedSource = MergingMediaSource(videoSource, audioSource)
            concatenatedSource.addMediaSource(mergedSource)
        }
        "stream" -> {
            val hlsSource = HlsMediaSource.Factory(cacheDataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(v.src))
            concatenatedSource.addMediaSource(hlsSource)
        }
    }
}

player.prepare(concatenatedSource)
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but there is an answer that might help you out here. How to play a particular video from ExoPlayer playlist android?

Comment: after reading this a bit more carefully is you problem with EXoplayer or recyclerview ? cus in this sentence you say "If the user clicks on a specific track from recyclerview I want to play all tracks but switch to clicked index." so you want the recyclerview to scroll?

Comment: is that true ? please read my previous comment

Comment: I don't want the recyclerview to scroll. I just want to switch to the media in exoplayer. for example if I add 5 videos to the exoplayer the user click on the third video it will open the player activity with all 5 videos and I want to switch to third video and start playing.